# Can one assert a mysterious, naturalistic explanation to undercut all god arguments?

Tags: atheism

I had been pondering this for a while and was wondering if there is any literature on the idea of undercutting **all** possible god hypotheses through the following trick (instead of simply saying that there’s no good reason to believe in a god).

Ignoring the ontological argument for a bit which is deductive, almost all arguments for a god rely on something that we see in the world that requires an explanation and then proposing that a god explains it.

My question is this: Instead of focusing on the fact that a god may be just an argument out of ignorance, or trying to find a naturalistic explanation, as most atheists do, can’t one just play the tu quoque card and simply assert a “mysterious” naturalistic hypothesis that is just as mysterious as the theistic one?

For example, suppose a theist says that the universe needs an explanation. Can’t one then just say that the universe is necessary through some unknown, mysterious way or made through some unknown, but godless, mysterious way? After all, when a god is proposed as an explanation for anything, that seems to execute their actual effect in completely unknown and mysterious ways, even by the theist’s own admission.

When someone says that fine tuning requires an explanation, can’t someone then say that the constants were just necessary in some mysterious way or has some other mysterious explanation that doesn’t involve a god?

It seems that **no matter** how reality turns out, the atheist seems to have a trump card. Sure, the atheist may not have an explanation for the beginning of the universe, but it seems that he can come up with a simpler and yet equally mysterious explanation as a god.

Note that the purpose of this wouldn’t be to come up with a serious competing hypotheses to theism. Rather, it would be to show how empty theistic explanations are. If one cannot rule out a mysterious natural explanation, then one is essentially never justified to believe in a god, which is just as mysterious but more complex.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149716/discussion-on-question-by-thinkingman-can-one-assert-a-mysterious-naturalistic); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: To me this seems related to questions like "does `supernatural` even make sense?" since anything that acts in this world is, at least in partially, part of this world.  I did a quick search but did not see an obvious case that this question had already been asked and answered here.

Answer (score 1):

One can always counter a mysterious explanation with a second explanation which is alike mysterious. But why should one do so?

The only reason I see is to show how mysterious the first explanation is. E.g., I consider this the driving force behind The Flying Spaghetti Monster "explanation".

It is no good idea to descend to the level of the proponent and to copy a strategy which oneself refuses.  Doing alike does not solve the original issue, at best it removes some obstacles on the way.

Comment: As mentioned in the post, it’s not meant to be a solution. It’s just to point out that god isn’t an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, it's a game open to all players. If you want to invoke an explanation that does away with god but relies instead on something like an imaginary power of nature, you are free to do so. You just need to make sure that you don't introduce anything that can be disproved, and you are up and running. One disadvantage of your approach, if your aim is to get support for the idea, is that it doesn't seem to be designed to hook in the gullible in quite the same way that some religions are. You need to introduce some motivation for belief, like the idea that doubters will burn in a fiery pit for eternity, while those who contribute to the financial standing of your institution will live forever in their idea of heaven. Some kind of inspirational backstory for the idea would be good too- maybe it was found on stone tablets by divers searching for Atlantis, or some such idea. Saying that it came up on Philosophy SE won't have the same cachet. You'll also need some mysterious guru-like figurehead to front the whole show, but you'll be  natural for that!

Comment: The aim isn’t to get support. It’s mainly just to show how empty theistic explanations are. If one cannot rule out a mysterious natural explanation, then one is essentially never justified to believe in god.

Comment: @MarcoOcram +1 for the stone tablets when searching for Atlantis :-)

Answer (score 1):

Both the *ancient Greek cosmogonical myth* and the *Ιndian* one, speak of a *cosmic egg* that contained inside it the *semen*, which *fertilized* the egg and the universe begun. The interest thing is that both myths are almost identical and do not consider a God-like entity to have been the cause of creation. Subsequently all Greek philosophers based their understanding of the creation in this context: *logos*. Note that the major eastern religions (Buddhism, Taoism and others) do not contain the concept of God either. Monotheistic religions personified these naturalistic *forces of creation* as a concrete entity: God.

In our days, all these discusions about *creation* - to my understanding - are just a conceptual inability to understand how can something be materialized without a cause or in other words, how can a cause be embedded/implanted in its actualization without an external intervention or design.

Answer (score 1):

One might say that such an assertion would undercut all *mysterianistic* God-based "arguments," but what about those which are not so mystery-minded? I would offer [*Axiogenesis: An Essay in Metaphysical Optimalism*](https://philpapers.org/rec/RESAAE) as a valiant attempt to demystify first the question, "Why is there something instead of nothing?" and then the possibility of at least Leibnizian creationism about the world (that a divine being created the world in an understandable way, for a generally, if not altogether particularly, understandable reason). To wit (this is less Rescher's reasoning *per se nota*, more mine, to be sure):

1. If it is possible for things to be created, it would be good to create them.
2. If something is good, it is possible at least in general.
3. Some possibilities require actual particulars to go through.
4. So for some examples of creation to be possible, it is required that there be some actuality beforehand.
5. Actual possibility is equivalent to possible actuality.
6. Possible actual possibility is equivalent to actual possible actuality.
7. (5) and (6) can be iterated an arbitrary/infinite number of times.
8. (Inference from the preceding) There is a possibly infinite amount of abstract actuality available for the sake of possible creation.
9. So, for some possible good things that we experience as actual also, we can infer that if they were creatable, and it would have been good if they were created, then the power of creation is intelligible modulo the possibility of their being created as good. QED

We would, then, assume somewhere various things about abstract goodness, abstract possibility, abstract actuality, abstract creatability, etc. but these assumptions are not necessarily incomprehensible, neither are they less (or even perhaps more) comprehensible than an unintentional, non-creationistic alternative (that the world exists just according to impersonal, general laws, say, and then either through otherwise-unfounded necessity or pure randomness). So to say, the abstract complexity of a set of impersonal laws of physics, dependent on (or constitutively reflected from) the domain of infinite mathematical possibility (e.g. Tegmark's Level 4 multiverse, or [Wolfram's "ruliad"](https://writings.stephenwolfram.com/2021/11/the-concept-of-the-ruliad/), or even Langan's ["self-configuring, self-processing language"](https://ctmucommunity.org/wiki/Self-Configuring_Self-Processing_Language) (when Langan's thesis is, *contra* its originator himself, not taken theologically)), is either *roughly* on a par, or otherwise incommensurate, with the abstract complexity of a self-aware *actus purus et ens simplicissimum* creating the world through, and as, a fountain of action-theoretic worth. QED, again, indeed...

---

Actually(!), if we go with Kant's diagnosis of the problem, the issue is more that the theistic explanation *isn't complex enough* compared to the non-theistic one, here: but also the non-theistic solution is *too complex*, taken at face value. This is insofar as Kant says [that the theism-friendly horns of the antinomian *dilemmatique* are one and all *too small* for the understanding, whereas the infinity-minded empiricist totalizations are *too large* for this](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Page%3ACritique_of_Pure_Reason_1855_Meiklejohn_tr.djvu/348). Whereof in this context, we might say that a mysterious empiricist explanation might be apparently ideologically *worse* than a mysterious theistic explanation, but non-mysterious empiricism is (again) roughly on the same footing, in a reciprocal manner, as mysterious theism.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.

If we take claims for which a god is offered as an explanation, we can roughly separate these into 2 categories:

- Claims that already have some reasonable or possible naturalistic explanation.

  This applies to most theistic claims. If nothing else, there's generally the possibility that someone is lying, that they were hallucinating or otherwise deceived, or that our models of physics are incomplete. Although there are commonly much more specific explanations.

  We can argue about how likely these things are, but such specific explanations would be much more rational than some mysterious alternative. Just because theists use it in their reasoning doesn't mean that's a rational thing to do.

  Although atheists are also fine with saying "I don't know", so this could arguably be the "mysterious" alternative that you're looking for.
- Claims that have no possible naturalistic explanation.

  There is arguably only 1 claim here (and we have no good reason to believe it's true): natural reality itself was caused by something (i.e. basically the premise of [the Kalam cosmological argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalam_cosmological_argument), as it's commonly used and understood).

  This is somewhere between [special pleading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_pleading), [moving the goalposts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_the_goalposts) and [begging the question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begging_the_question) (or just a questionable assertion): if you were to propose anything natural that caused natural reality, that in itself is part of natural reality and the theist can just say that was caused by something. We've gotten all the way back to the Big Bang, and now they say "well, what caused the Big Bang" (never mind that they typically strawman that as something coming from nothing, even though it's only really apologists who are making that claim).

  The very claim that they're looking to find an explanation for is already  asserting that there's something outside of the natural world, and only really a deity would meet that criteria.

  So a natural explanation wouldn't make sense for that claim, but we can instead point out that they're begging the question.

Comment: As mentioned in the post, it’s not meant to be a solution. It’s just to point out that god isn’t an explanation. In the case you described, one can posit no cause, some timeless cause, or any other non intentional cause that has simpler attributes than god, let’s call it Mod. If the theist can’t rule out Mod which is simpler yet explains the same thing, there is no reason to believe in an omnipotent, omniscient God.

Comment: @thinkingman What you're saying basically already happens. In discussions, atheists frequently replace "God" with something else to demonstrate the problem with theist claims. Roland the closet goblin is commonly said to possess all the traits that theists say God possesses. And he also lives in a closet. Does God do that? I don't think so. So obviously Roland is better, then.

Comment: Sure although that is an example that still proposes a designer. One can instead just propose that nature, through some means, produced that phenomenon. It may even be asserted that in the universe’s case, its initial state was simply necessary. After all, God is considered necessary, so one can just push it back. Although this brings in the issue of whether something can begin uncaused which is a whole different debate.

Comment: @thinkingman "It may even be asserted that in the universe’s case, its initial state was simply necessary" - I have heard atheists use this response quite a few times, and may have used it myself too. "the issue of whether something can begin uncaused" - God doesn't actually solve that problem, though, because God would then be uncaused instead of the universe. Whatever criteria allows that to happen could also be asserted for the universe, or some part of it (e.g. God is eternal -> the universe is eternal).

Comment: Yeah, I agree, with one caveat. If one presumes that the scientific evidence behind the universe having a beginning is correct, it cannot be posited to be eternal. However, what one can posit, is some other form of intentionless “stuff” existing before or timelessly transforming into the universe. I suppose one can also just assume science may be wrong and say that the universe is eternal. After all, the god proponent is also denying some form of inductive evidence which suggests that immaterial bodiless mindful beings can’t exist. @NotThatGuy

Comment: @thinkingman We don't have evidence of the "beginning" of the universe. We merely managed to trace things back to a certain point, where our models start breaking down. Given general relativity, our concept of time breaks down too, so there may or may not exist a "before" prior to that point.

Comment: Yeah I suppose I mentioned that partially because the notion of something having only a finite past (in the case of the universe) seems counter intuitive. By beginning, that’s all I mean: having a finite past. Of course, physics does not have to agree with my intuitions. At the same time, I just think physics in general at that point is too speculative to be able to decide this matter. @NotThatGuy